# is there any way to push the following file in adb using python scripting?

Tags: python, android, python-2.7, subprocess, adb

```
subprocess.call ('adb push \\C:\Dropbox\note\jsmpath.txt\ /sdcard/diag_logs \n',shell = True)
```

I am trying to push the following file but it showing up an error that I need arguments, I indeed have given the source and destination path
any leads will be helpful

Thanks a ton in advance

Answer (score 0):

`\n` denotes a newline character, so `'C:\Dropbox\note'` would be interpreted as two lines of:

```
C:\Dropbox
ote
```

You can use a raw string (with an `r` in front of the string literal) instead to keep backslashes from being interpreted, and remove the unnecessary trailing newline character:

```
subprocess.call(r'adb push C:\Dropbox\note\jsmpath.txt /sdcard/diag_logs', shell=True)
```

Comment: You also have unnecessary backslashes around the path. I've now removed them for you.